# How to draw a number inside a circle on Google Map with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know the similar questions have been asked before, but they are all in Android (Java).

While I need to draw a text inside a yellow circle (let's call the text + its outside circle a unit) on Google Map with JavaScript (take a look the picture below):

[image]

I looked into Google Map JavaScript API and only found the code about draw shapes on google map but cannot find any code which gives me an insight of drawing an unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in option.

possible workarounds:

- a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays)(`circles` may be created via [css](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles)) [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4jSP7/)
- a serverside script that creates images with circle+number on the fly (based on url-parameters). These images may be used as icon

Comment: wow, you are my hero! Is it possible to stick the unit at a specific geo-location?so when users drag and move maps, the unit will follow. cheers

Comment: the unit is sticky(it will follow when you drag the map), but the overlay is draggable too(the original task for this demo was to create a draggable custom overlay, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127626/can-we-make-custom-overlays-draggable-on-google-maps-v3/22143588#22143588). You only need to remove the drag-functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4jSP7/11/

Comment: excellent! Also, Dr.Molle, do you know how to add a map listener in SenCha Touch? I have asked that question for days, but no one has answered it....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865259/how-to-add-map-listeners-onto-map-page

Comment: I'm not familiar with SenCha Touch, sorry.