# How to add map listeners onto map page

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch

How to I add a map listener to my first map page?
I saw many examples which create a map and put it into a page, but here in my code, the map itself is a page.
So I do not know how to add map listeners in this way.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    fullscreen: true,
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.Map',
        'Ext.Panel',
        'Ext.tab.*',
        'Ext.*'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

      items: [
            {
                title: 'WebTrack',
                iconCls:'maps',
                xtype: 'map',
                useCurrentLocation: true,
                store: 'my.store.appleStore',

            }
```

Can someone help please?

Thanks very much

Comment: Hi friends~~~any input/advice or answers are welcome~~~ please say something~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

Steps to follow:

1. create a map component in controller.
2. Ext.define('myapp.controller.Noises', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
       requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],
       config: {
           refs: {
               mapComponent: 'main map'
           },
           control: {
               mapComponent: {
                   maprender: 'onMaprender'
               }
           }
       },

So the onMapprender is where you can start to write your code.

Hope it helps.

Cheers