# Google Map Custom OverlayView got drawn several times

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My custom Google Map overlayview gets drawn several times.

I searched the similar question and found them in Java not in Javascript.

Here is my code :

```
DraggableOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var container = document.createElement('div'),
        that = this;

    if (typeof this.get('content').nodeName !== 'undefined') {
        container.appendChild(this.get('content'));
    } else {
        if (typeof this.get('content') === 'string') {
            container.innerHTML = this.get('content');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.draggable = true;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.get('map').getDiv(),
        'mouseleave',

    function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(container, 'mouseup');
    });


    this.set('container', container)

    if (!this.getPanes()) {
        return;
    }

    this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(container);
}


DraggableOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {

    if (!this.getProjection()) {
        return;
    }

    var pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

    if (!this.get('container')) {
        return;
    }

    this.get('container').style.left = pos.x + 'px';
    this.get('container').style.top = pos.y + 'px';
};
```

But I only draw it once. How does it get drawn several times?

Does anyone meet this issue before?

Thank you.

Comment: *But I only draw it once* ....difficult to give an answer , creating a class does nothing, how do you use the class? The (my guess) original code ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127626/can-we-make-custom-overlays-draggable-on-google-maps-v3/22143588#22143588 )  doesn't create duplicates.

Comment: hi @Dr.Molle  thank you for your advice. I have solved this problem by  simply storing each of custom markers into an array and remove them lately.